# Sum of two random variables uniform on (a,b)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convolution

There is much information about the probability density function of the sum of two iid variables which are uniform on [0,1]. I am trying to derive a general probability density formula for the sum of two iid variables, $X_1$ and $X_2$, which are uniform on $(a,b)$. For $Y = X_1 + X_2$ I was able to obtain the following formula geometrically:
 $$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{y-2a}{(b-a)^2} & \text{for $2a < y < a+b$} \\
\frac{2b-y}{(b-a)^2} & \text{for $a+b \le y < 2b$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

However, I am trying to arrive at this formula using convolution. I know we start with $$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X_1}(x)f_{X_2}(y-x)\,dx.$$ 
Then because $f_X(x) = 1$ if $a\le x\le b$ we have $\int_a^b f_{X_2}(y-x)\,dx$. I don't really understand where I'm supposed to go from here. Any help or explanation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks very much like your answer follows along [from here](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter7.pdf). However, you missed a crucial part when generalizing.

$f_{X_1}(x) = \dfrac{1}{b-a}$ when $a \leq x \leq b$ and $0$ otherwise so your convolution becomes

$$f_Y(y) = \int_a^b f_{X_2}(y-x) \dfrac{1}{b-a} dx$$

Now this is $0$ unless $a \leq y -x \leq b$ or stated otherwise, when $y-b \leq x \leq y-a$ in which case $f_Y(\cdot) = 1$. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: I know this is when I need to break the problem up into two cases, one where  $2a \lt y \lt a+b$ and one where $a+b \leq y \lt 2b$. In the example referenced, doing this changes the limits of integration but I'm having trouble understanding where the new limits come from.